# How to set reverse ptr in azure Cli?

Tags: email-server, azure, ptr-record, azure-networking

I'm trying to add reverse ptr on my Azure VM server.
I tried via powershell and now I'm trying CLI direct on Azure panel.
NOTE: My VMs are static ip.

```
az network public-ip update --resource-group VMEmailWMB --name PublicIp --reverse-fqdn mydomain.com.br.
```

As pictured below it appears that the resource was not found.[image]

I believe the resource is that of my VM.

After this code works, will that alone be enough to host an email server?

*English by Google Translator*

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, could you use CLI 2.0 command to list your resource group, in this way we can check it. We can use this command `az group list` to list all resource group in your subscription.

By the way, to add reverse DNS to an existing PublicIpAddress that **doesn't** already have a DNS name, you must also **specify a DNS name**:

```
az network public-ip create --name yourPublicIpname --resource-group MyResourceGroup --location westcentralus --dns-name contosoapp1 --reverse-fqdn contosoapp1.westcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

> will that alone be enough to host an email server?

Do you mean does this FQDN only work for you, not share to others? If yes, your are right, this FQDN only work for your Azure VM.

If you want to use this FQDN to host your email and want to send emails to external domains from Azure VM, the answer is **no**, Azure does not support this.

Sending outbound e-mail to external domains (such as outlook.com, gmail.com, etc) directly from an e-mail server hosted in Azure compute services is **not** supported due to the elastic nature of public cloud service IPs and the potential for abuse.

If you want to send e-mails to external domains from Azure compute resource is via **SMTP** relay. More information please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2016/04/04/sending-e-mail-from-azure-compute-resource-to-external-domains/).

Comment: i receive this error:

ReverseFqdn {mydomain}.com.br that PublicIPAddress VMEmailWM-ip is trying to use does not belong to subscription 84d9a23a-{***********}. One of the following conditions need to be met to establish ownership:
 1) ReverseFqdn matches fqdn of any public ip resource under the subscription; 
 2) ReverseFqdn resolves to the fqdn (through CName records chain) of any public ip resource under the subcription; 
 3) It resolves to the ip address (through CName and A records chain) of a static public ip resource under the subscription.

Comment: Does this publicipaddress under your current subscription? can your list your public IP address by this command `az network public-ip list`?